# Who was the first one to rigorously show that quantum fields are operator-valued distributions?

Tags: mathematics, reference-request, quantum-field-theory

Any Wightman-based approach to Axiomatical Quantum Field Theory states that quantum fields are (operator-valued) distributions. Is there a first rigorous proof of this fact which became trivial as early as 1970? Maybe the name of the person is K. Friedrich or A. Wightman, but I want the exact reference for the proof.

Comment: Proof of what? AQFT simply formalizes quantum fields as operator based distributions. There is no proving that something formal formalizes something informal, one can only prove things about formalizations themselves.

Comment: Then a simple mathematical proof that fields need to be distributions would do. It is heuristically present in various sources, but I need the first proof with mathematical rigor.

Comment: Could you give a specific source and what exactly is being proved from what? I have trouble understanding how heuristic considerations about what formal model to choose can be "proved with mathematical rigor".

Comment: Sure, in section 12 of Geroch Notes on QFT: https://www.amazon.com/Quantum-Field-Theory-Lecture-Notes-ebook/dp/B01J2GRGWC/ref=sr_1_11?dchild=1&keywords=Geroch+Robert&qid=1607990797&sr=8-11#reader_B01J2GRGWC. Here he justifies (without proof) that the sums 141/142/143 do not converge, so he says they need to be smeared (so transformed from functions to distributions). My question: who proved this (not necessarily in the context of a scalar quantum field) transformation from functions to distributions first and where?

Comment: Also the comment by Streater & Wightman in their AQFT book on page 97 is also heuristic (he says that classical fields such as the em field) also need a reinterpretation as distributions, so this is then natural for quantum fields.